# files are removed from their origin when copied on external media

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, transfer, drag-and-drop

if I transfer data (drag and drop) on the icon of an external media ( hard drive, pendrive..) they are moved and original files are removed from their origin. If I open the window of the media, then it is normally copied without removing original files.

I have lost many files due to that problem, assuming having original file and deleting the copy on external media. It's real problem.

Any idea?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, and which applications, like Files, do you use for the transfer? Moves to a different device should not delete the original, but moves to the same device will.

Comment: hello i use 20.04 and desktop idon ng (ding)